# change plotting range/limits of graphics::image function

Tags: r

Must be a fairly obvious one, but how can I get `image` to fill the whole plotting area when adding it to an existing plot, not just the upper right part from [0,1]?

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), yaxs="i", xaxs="i")
image(volcano, add=T)
```

[image]

```
image(volcano, add=T, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1))
```

This does not do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose two options would be possible. Either interpolate values by expanding the image or put the volcano raster in as a background image. Third option would be to transform all your data points which you would normally plot on [-1, 1], to fit the [0, 1] scale.

Comment: @imo Note that I want to ADD the image to an existing plot. I made that clearer in the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like the default `x` and `y` values used by `image()`, you can specify them yourself. Here's how the default work in the function

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), yaxs="i", xaxs="i")    
image(seq.int(-1, 1, length.out = nrow(volcano)), 
   seq(-1, 1, length.out = ncol(volcano)),
   volcano)
```

[image]

Comment: ah, that was simple. I just failed to note the `x` and `y` args. Thanks :)